# Jsoup - extracting data from an <a> tag, inside a <td> tag

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to extract data from a Web site, using Jsoup. The data are in a table.

HTML code:

```
<table><tr><td><a href="......">Pop.Density</a></td>
           <td>123</td></tr></table>
```

I want to print:

```
zip code...(taken from a text file): 123
```

I have the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

This is my code:

```
String s = br.readLine();
String str="http://www.bestplaces.net/people/zip-code/illinois/"+s;

org.jsoup.Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(str);
conn.timeout(1800000); 
Document doc = conn.get();

for (Element table : doc.select("table"))
{
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) 
    {
    Elements tds = row.select("td");
    if (tds.size() > 1)
    {
        Element link = tds.get(0).select("a").first();
        String linkText = link.text();

        if (link.text().contains("Pop.Density"))
            System.out.println(s+","+tds.get(1).text());
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
If I modify the last if():

```
if (tds.get(0).select("a").text().contains("Pop.Density"))
```

I do not have any exceptions, but no output either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the shared html is not the real one being used, I think its throwing the exception when first TD doesn't have `<a>` tag. I think you need to update

```
  if (tds.size() > 1)
```

as

```
  if (tds.size() > 1 && tds.get(0).select("a") != null 
                          && tds.get(0).select("a").first() ! null)
```

If this is not the case, sharing the line number of `NullPointerException` origin can help better finding the solution.

Comment: I changed the code, but the program throws the same exception.

Comment: This line causes me problems: String linkText = link.text();

Comment: Ohh in that case, select is returning empty array. I updated the answer. Added one more null check

Comment: No exception, but no output (:

Comment: It confirm its not finding the link element and hence was the exception. Your traversal is having some issue. Share me your full input html.

Comment: You have the link in the code: http://www.bestplaces.net/people/zip-code/illinois/....   I do not know if I am allowed to give you the zip code, one of my questions was closed as too localized, because I reffered to a specific zip code, but you can figure out: name_city/zipcode at the end of URL

Comment: Any solution? That <a> tag, gives me headache.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was a small typing error: if (link.text().contains("Pop. Density")). One space between Pop. and Density. I did not see it on the full HTML input. But, you give me the solution for my question actually, my problem with the exception, so I will accept and upvote your answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sorry I just got back Good to know it is resolved. Thanks for updating!!